# How to get nested property value from object in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Consider situation where in Groovy you have type `Company`:

```
class Company {
  def name
  def contactPerson
}
```

and `contactPerson` of `Contact` type:

```
class Contact {
  def firstName
  def lastName
  def email
}
```

Then we have instance of Company class:

```
def stackOverflow = new Company(
  name: "Stack Overflow",
  contactPerson: new Contact(
    firstName: "Joel",
    lastName: "Spolsky",
    email: "joel.spolsky@stackoverflow.com"
  )
)
```

In Groovy we simple have:

```
assert stackOverflow.contactPerson.firstName == "Joel"
```

or:

```
assert stackOverflow['contactPerson']['firstName'] == "Joel"
```

and also:

```
assert stackOverflow.name == "Stack Overflow"
```

or:

```
assert stackOverflow['name'] == "Stack Overflow"
```

or even:

```
def fieldName = 'name'
assert stackOverflow.${fieldName} == "Stack Overflow"
```

But suppose we have:

```
def nestedFieldName = 'contactPerson.firstName'
```

Is there a Groovy-way to achieve something like this:

```
assert stackOverflow.${nestedFieldName} == "Joel"
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to reduce a sequence of keys:

```
nestedFieldName.split('\\.')
    .inject(stackOverflow) { object, property -> 
        object[property]
     }
```

Which returns `'Joel'`, and could be used to read values at arbitrary depths.