# Get LinkedHashMapValue with Dynamic Key

Tags: java, groovy

I want to get the value from LinkedHashmap with dynamic key like below.

```
def map = [Employee1: [Status: 'Working', Id: 1], Employee2:  [Status: 'Resigned', Id: 2]]

def keys = "Employee1.Status"
def keyPath = "";
def keyList = keys.tokenize(".");


keyList.eachWithIndex() { key, i ->

    keyPath += "$key"

    if(i != keyList.size() - 1){   keyPath += "."     } 
}

println keyPath //Employee1.Status
println map.keyPath //Always null
println map.'Employee1'.'Status' //Working
println map.Employee1.Status //Working
```

Here `map.keyPath` always returning `null`. How to get the value with dynamic key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get nested property value from object in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947612/how-to-get-nested-property-value-from-object-in-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply do this:

```
def tmpMap = map;
keyList.subList(0, keyList.size - 1).each {key -> 
   tmpMap = map[key]    
}
println tmpMap[keyList[keyList.size - 1]]
```

This will extract the sub maps until the actual value key is reached. To make this more stable you should add some logic to check if the value associated with the current key is actually a map.

Answer (score 2):

With curiosity I try to use just Your code.

`keyPath` ==  'Employee1.Status' not 'Employee1'.'Status'

So to do this you can make something like this:

```
def map = [
    Employee1: 
    [Status: 'Working', Id: 1], 
    Employee2:  
    [Status: 'Resigned', Id: 2]
    ]

def keys = "Employee1.Status"
def keyPath = "";
def keyList = keys.tokenize(".");



keyList.eachWithIndex() { key, i ->

    keyPath += "$key"
    if(i != keyList.size() - 1){   keyPath += '.'     } 

}

println keyPath //Employee1.Status
//tokenize it and get elements as a[0] and a[1]
a = keyPath.tokenize(".");
println map.(a[0]).(a[1]) //Working
println map.'Employee1'.'Status' //Working
println map.Employee1.Status //Working
```